# 日本語に違和感 - 最近次に授与されました:

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語, モバイル

URL(例)
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed

---

モバイル版

> 最近次に授与されました:

という言い方はおかしいと思います。

> 最近授与されたユーザー

がいいと思います。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transifexにて変更しました、近日中に反映される予定です。

Comment: 確認してみると反映されてますね。ありがとうございます